# Should I say "I saw the same products in 'another' / 'other' place for half cost"

Tags: adjectives

What would be better in the next sentence? To use **other** or **another**?

> "I don't want this product because I saw the same products in **another**
>   place for half cost"

Comment: *other* requires a *determiner* when followed by a singular noun. *Another* is actually *an other* i.e. alternative/different. If it's one store with half price, use 'another' (never use 'another' with plural because it's 'an another'). If there are a couple, '....other places...'.

Comment: Further reading is here on [Cambridge's English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/other-others-the-other-or-another)

Comment: Should be "... **for half the price**, not _for half cost_.

Answer (score 2):

"Another" is constructed from "other" with a definite article ("an") added to it. Therefore, since you presumably mean that you only saw a better price in a single, definite place, use "another" rather than "other". If you've seen better prices in more than one place, say, "I don't want this product because I saw the same products in **other places** for half cost"

Also, although it's very hard to pin down all of the differences in usage, I'd use "price" rather than "cost". When talking about money, "price" usually means the amount that was asked, while "cost" usually means the amount that was paid. Since, in your case, your statement does not say that you actually bought the items offered for less, "price" is the word to use. It gets a little tricky when you pay the amount asked - then the price *is* the cost, and you can use either, although in my (American) experience, "price" is more often used.